# Changing the priority of rules in Make

Tags: makefile

The situation below is simplified heavily, but it does reflect the problem I'm having.

I have a Makefile that looks like this:

```
prefix-%.zip: prefix-%
    zip -r $@ $<

prefix-%: base
    cp -r base $@
```

This is placed in a directory together with another directory base containing some files. If I execute the command

```
make prefix-1.zip
```

I would like the directory `prefix-1` to be created using the second rule, and then the zip file `prefix-1.zip` to be created based on that directory using the first rule.

However, it seems like it finds the first rule with the stem '1', but it doesn't pick that rule, because the directory doesn't exist. It then seems to favour the second rule with the stem '1.zip'. Although this is a longer stem, that rule gets picked. I assume that this is due to the missing prerequisite for the first rule. Is there some way I can guide Make to the right rule, without manually first making the directory?

Btw, first making the directory and then the zip file works

```
make prefix-1
make prefix-1.zip
```

Comment: While this question is way older, this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43724971/prioritizing-pattern-rules-in-make has got more visibility and has attracted a better answers, thanks to mentioning patterns (which this one is also about).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a kludge, but it works:

```
prefix-%.zip: prefix-%
    zip -r $@ $<

prefix-%: base | dummy%
    cp -r base $@

dummy%:
    @:
```

According to the manual, ["a rule whose prerequisites actually exist or are mentioned always takes priority over a rule with prerequisites that must be made by chaining other implicit rules."](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Match) So we make the second rule less attractive by giving it a dummy prerequisite that must be chained. Crude but effective. And we use the pipe (`|`) to make it an "order-only" prerequisite, so as not to force the directory to be rebuilt needlessly.

Comment: That's indeed a kludge, but I guess it is closest to what I want to do. I'll think about whether that's really what I want to do. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```
prefix-%.zip: base
    cp -r base $(subst .zip,,$@)
    zip -r $@ $(subst .zip,,$@)
```

I use the [subst](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/make/make_8.html#SEC73) function to strip out the `.zip` extension by replacing `.zip` with the empty string.