# Prioritizing pattern rules in Make

Tags: sorting, makefile

I have (roughly) this Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all
.SUFFIXES:

OUT = /www/web

all: $(OUT)/index.html

# rule 1
%.html: %.in
    build_html $< $@

# rule 2
$(OUT)/%: %
    cp $< $@
```

This Makefile has a problem, since there are two different ways to build `$(OUT)/index.html`:

1. build `./index.html` (rule 1), then copy it to `$(OUT)` (rule 2).
2. copy `./index.in` to `$(OUT)` (rule 2), then build `$(OUT)/index.html` (rule 1).

I want `make` to *always* prefer option 1. How can I indicate that there is a preferred order between these two pattern rules?

(I can think of a few hacky ways to accomplish it for this particular case, but I want a solution that is as general as possible---for instance, changing the pattern of rule 2 to `$(OUT)/%.html: %.html` will fix the problem, but loses generality since I need to repeat myself if I want to handle other kinds of files in the same way later.)

Comment: It should _always_ prefer rule 1 as is...   Makefile will choose the rule with the shortest stem, and in rule1 the stem will be `index`, and rule 2, the stem would be `index.html`...   (I'm assuming gnu make here).   Are you seeing something different?

Comment: (sorry, that previous comment should have mentioned `index.in` rather than `index.html`, but `index.in` is still longer than `index`).

Comment: I observe the undesirable behavior (option 2). I am using GNU Make 3.81. I think you have misinterpreted how the "shortest stem" heuristic affects the build order here: it will force the undesirable behavior, not the good behavior! The top-level goal is `$(OUT)/index.html`, and rule 1 matches best (shortest stem). Rule 1 says we need `$(OUT)/index.in`, and only rule 2 matches that.

Comment: You didn't say you were using GNU make 3.81, before.  The shortest stem behavior was introduced in GNU make 3.82.  In prior releases, the patterns were tried in the order they were defined in the makefile and the first one that matched was used.

Comment: @MadScientist good point. Even so, I am pretty sure that you will see the wrong behavior for the reason I described above.

Comment: No, the stem is the part that matches the `%`.  If the target is `/www/web/index.html` then it matches `%.html` with `%` as `/www/web/index` and it matches `$(OUT)/%` with `%` as `index.html`.  So rule #2 is the shorter stem.

Comment: If you want this makefile to behave the same with <=3.81 and >=3.82 you need to put rule #2 first, then it will work the same for all versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [quote](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Match.html#Pattern-Match) from the GNU Makefile Manual:

> It is possible that more than one pattern rule will meet these criteria. In that case, make will choose the rule with the shortest stem (that is, the pattern that matches most specifically). If more than one pattern rule has the shortest stem, make will choose the first one found in the makefile.

So, you can try to create rules which ensure shorter stems to take priority.   Alternatively, you could use [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage) to limit the scope of what gets copied where, as so:

```
%.html: %.in
      build_html $@ $<

$(expected_out) : (OBJS)/% : %
      cp $@ $<
```

and then prepopulate `$(expected_out)` with what you want in there.  Finally, you can add:

```
$(OUT)/index.html : index.html
```

somewhere in your makefile, as make prefers the 'shortest path' to building an object, which would only be one pattern rule in this case.

Comment: Static pattern rules seem like they might be very helpful here. I think your hack to extend the length of the stem is off: the stem is just the part that matches the `%`, making it the same for each case.

Comment: Ok, removing hack.   I just tried it, and make chooses the shortest stem for the _first_ rule to be run, not the longest stem on the chain of rules to be run.

Answer (score 1):

While @John's answer best fits my use-case (I know exactly what files belong in `$(OUT)`), there is also an alternative solution: mark the desired intermediate file as "precious".

```
.PRECIOUS: index.html
```

This will also instruct Make not to delete `index.html`, which it would otherwise do for you.

This works thanks to [Make's algorithm for choosing implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rule-Search-Algorithm). Make favors rules whose dependencies exist or ought to exist, and a file "ought to exist" if it has an explicit rule or is a dependency of another rule. This applies even if it is a dependency of a special target like `.SECONDARY`, `.INTERMEDIATE`, or `.PRECIOUS`. For more info, also see the [manual section on "Chains of Implicit Rules"](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Chained-Rules).